# How to provide system message variables and human message variables to an LLMChain (LangChain with Python)?

Tags: python, langchain, py-langchain, openair

I have a problem sending system messagge variables and human message variables to a prompt through LLMChain.

I have the following code:

```
prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
    [
        SystemMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(
            "You are a {role} having a conversation with a human. Talk as a {role}."
        ), 
        MessagesPlaceholder(
            variable_name="chat_history"
        ),  
        HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(
            "{human_input}"
        ),  
    ]
)

memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True)

llm = ChatOpenAI()

chat_llm_chain = LLMChain(
    llm=llm,
    prompt=prompt,
    verbose=True,
    memory=memory,
)

chat_llm_chain.predict(human_input="Hi there my friend", role='dog')
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
raise ValueError(f"One input key expected got {prompt_input_keys}")
ValueError: One input key expected got ['human_input', 'role']
```

**How can I send the role variable? Is there any better way to handle this?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple inputs, should assign a input key.
Just like this:

```
memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True, input_key="human_input", output_key="<***>")
```

Notice that output key is not necessary.

For more information, cliek [this](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/memory/adding_memory_chain_multiple_inputs)

Or you can delete memory, this error occurs when conversion finished and save chat history into memory but you have more than one input.

Comment: My problem is that in the LLMChain instance, there is no place to send the SystemMessagePromptTemplate input key. I can only send the HumanMessagePromptTemplate key.

Comment: In your example, you have already sent sys prompt, please see the outpur of verbose. You can set role to be dog or robot, then it response different.